# jtable checkbox single selection java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a jtable. I put checkbox in a column. But the check box are in multi selection mode,ie in my jtable there are 5 checkbox. i can select 5 of 5. I want to select only 1 at a time.
How can I change it to single selection?

My code is like :

```
TableColumn colTable2 = jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);

colTable2.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jCheckBox2));
colTable2.setCellRenderer(jTable2.getDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a checkbox is either selected or not - nothing multiple that I can see. In other words: what do you _mean_?

Comment: in my jtable there are 5 checkbox. i can select 5 of 5. I want to select only 1 at a time.

Comment: thanks for the clarification - you might consider to edit your question and add the additional info there

Comment: that logic belongs into your TableModel: in setValueAt which sets the corresponding value to true, check which is the current true and set that to false

Comment: @kleopatra:: Thanks a lot.... I have done it with setValueAt function.

Answer (score 1):

In your table model, when one of the 5 columns value is set to true, you should set the one which is currently true to false and fire a table model event for this column as well.

You should also consider using a radio button as renderer and editor, since it's the most appropriate component to represent a unique selection.

The alternative is to replace these 5 columns by a single one, and use a combo box as cell editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you an alternative approach,

Have a look at [JRadioButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html), I guess this will be a better option.

Note , from [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

> Check boxes are similar to radio buttons but their selection model is different, by convention. Any number of check boxes in a group — none, some, or all — can be selected. A group of radio buttons, on the other hand, can have only one button selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a TableModel that introduces a single selection check box column at the end of an existing table.
You can install it like this

```
CheckBoxSelectionTableModel.register(table);
```

You can give it a try on the [SimpleTableDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SimpleTableDemoProject/src/components/SimpleTableDemo.java) - it will look like the following and keep the selected row in sync with the check box.

[image]

It only requires the existing table Model to be an instance of *javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel* - which will be the case in > 80%.

```
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class CheckBoxSelectionTableModel implements TableModel, ListSelectionListener {

  protected final AbstractTableModel delegate;
  protected int selectedRow = -1;
  protected final ListSelectionModel selectionModel;

  public CheckBoxSelectionTableModel(AbstractTableModel delegate, ListSelectionModel selectionModel) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
    this.selectionModel = selectionModel;
    selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(this);
  }

  public static void register(JTable table) {
    table.setModel(new CheckBoxSelectionTableModel((AbstractTableModel)table.getModel(), table.getSelectionModel()));
  }

  protected boolean isCheckBoxCloumn(int columnIndex) {
    return columnIndex == getCheckBoxColumnIndex();
  }

  protected int getCheckBoxColumnIndex() {
    return delegate.getColumnCount();
  }

  // --------------------- delegate methods --------------------- \\

  public int getRowCount() {
    return delegate.getRowCount();
  }

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return getCheckBoxColumnIndex()+1;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
    return isCheckBoxCloumn(columnIndex) ? "" : delegate.getColumnName(columnIndex);
  }


  public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
    return isCheckBoxCloumn(columnIndex) ? Boolean.class : delegate.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return isCheckBoxCloumn(columnIndex) ? true : delegate.isCellEditable(rowIndex, columnIndex);
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    return  isCheckBoxCloumn(columnIndex) ?  rowIndex == selectedRow : delegate.getValueAt(rowIndex, columnIndex);
  }    

  public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if(isCheckBoxCloumn(columnIndex)) {
      int lastSelected = selectedRow;
      if((Boolean) aValue){
        selectedRow = rowIndex;
      } else {
        selectionModel.clearSelection();
        selectedRow = -1;
      }
      if(lastSelected > -1) {
        delegate.fireTableRowsUpdated(lastSelected, lastSelected);
      }
      delegate.fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    } else {
      delegate.setValueAt(aValue, rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
  }

  public void addTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
    delegate.addTableModelListener(l);
  }

  public void removeTableModelListener(TableModelListener l) {
    delegate.removeTableModelListener(l);
  }

  // --------------------- ListSelectionListener methods --------------------- \\

  @Override
  public void valueChanged(final ListSelectionEvent e) {
    if(e.getValueIsAdjusting()){
      return;
    }
    int index = selectionModel.getLeadSelectionIndex();
    boolean isSelected = selectionModel.isSelectedIndex(index);
    setValueAt(isSelected ,index , getCheckBoxColumnIndex());     
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking something for this issue and I came to this solution... hope its helps someone.

```
private void MiTablaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    for(int i=0; i<MiTabla.getRowCount(); i++){
        if(i==MiTabla.getSelectedRow()){
            MiTabla.setValueAt(true, MiTabla.getSelectedRow(), 0);
        }else{
            MiTabla.setValueAt(false, i, 0);
        }
    }

}
```